# append pd.ExcelWriter got KeyError: 'Sheet1'

Tags: python

I am trying to write an excel append function for Dataframe but I got an error prompt `KeyError 'Sheet1'`. I have tried to remove

```
startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row
```

from first statement of writer function.  No error prompted but Dataframe for `dfoutput_Financial` overwrite previous excel record and put it in the 1 row of excel file and `dfoutput_PL` was appended at max row of excel file. 
How to solve `KeyError 'Sheet1'` issue?

**Code**

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
dfoutput_Financial.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row, index=False, header= False)
dfoutput_PL.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row, index=False, header= False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to add "workbook"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `KeyError` for Sheet1 because "Sheet1" doesn't exist in `writer.sheets`.
To solve this you must load your workbook before using it.
Like This.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

#Load Workbook
writer.book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer.sheets =  {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
startrow = writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row
```

If you still get `KeyError` for "Sheet1" then check if it really exists in `test.xlsx`
`